# stream output and implicit void* cast operator function invocation

Tags: c++

a code like

```
cin>> grade;
```

where grade is a standard data type returns a reference to cin(istream object) which enables cascaded inputs....
but i read that if

```
cin >>grade;
```

is used as a condition say in a while statement...the stream's void* cast operator function is called implicitly...and it converts reference to istream object into a non-null or null pointer depending upon success or failure of last input operation...and null pointer converts to false and non-null to true...my questions are:

1. what is the void * cast operator function and how does it work here
2. how is non-null pointer converted to true and null to false

Comment: Just to note why this is useful: It allows you to loop like `while(cin >> x) { /* do stuff with x */ }`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1.what is the void * cast operator function and how does it work here

It looks something like this:

```
operator void* () const {
    return fail() ? 0 : this;
}
```

The question is: why isn’t an `operator bool` used here? The answer is: because that allows invalid conversions which may hide bugs. The above is an example of the [**safe bool idiom**](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).

However, this implementation is actually obsolete. There exist better implementations of this idiom; the article explains them.

> 2.how is non-null pointer converted to true and null to false

This is just how C++ works: any non-null pointer is considered equivalent to `true` in a conditional. Now, why does C++ invoke the `operator void*` here in the first place?

Essentially, when C++ sees an object of an unexpected type, it tries to apply *one* implicit conversion that would make the object type valid in this context. The compiler therefore tries out all available implicit conversions and looks whether the resulting type would be acceptable in this context.

This is happening her: the compiler sees `while (cin >> grade)`. It knows that `basic_istream` isn’t valid in the context of a `while` conditional. So it finds that there is an `operator void*`, and a `void*` *is* valid in this context so C++ applies this conversion.

Comment: @Konrad: Is this not enough -> `return fail() ? 0 : this;` ?

Comment: @Nawaz Wasn’t sure, and too lazy to check. ?: forbids implicit conversion between incompatible types. Perhaps `0`’s type is correctly inferred as `basic_istream*` here. But either way the cast makes this explicit.

Comment: @Konrad: Yes. `0` is compatible with any type of pointer, due to implicit conversion. That is the reason its often used as NULL pointer of any type. `std::istream *p = 0;`, `std::string *s=0;`,  `void* v = 0;` all are fine. Anyway, +1 for good answer.

Comment: @Nawaz These are different situations however, because they are initialisations. Initialisations can also call implicit conversion operators, and `?:` *cannot* do that.

Comment: @avinash Not necessarily. This is just a typical implementation. In reality, any pointer value != 0 will do, for example `reinterpret_cast<void*>(1)`.

Comment: @Konrad: `?:` may implicitly convert one type into another whichever way is possible : http://www.ideone.com/grz1E

Comment: @konrad but i also wanted to know how is this void* operator func implicitly called?

Comment: @avinash Good question, see updated answer. I had thought that the safe bool article explained this but it doesn’t really.

Comment: @konrad is operator void*() const{//body} same as void* operator(){} and if yes why is only this function called there might be other func with pointer return type

Comment: @avinash No. `operator T()` is a special syntax to declare an implicit conversion operator to type `T`. As to why only this function is called: because it’s the only implicit operator that can be called on `basic_ostream` that is valid in the context of `while`.