# How do I make a class in C++, when initialized, return a boolean value when its name is invoked, but no explicit function call make, like ifstream

Tags: c++, class

How do I make a class in C++, when initialized, return a Boolean value when its name is invoked, but no explicit function call make, like ifstream.  I want to be able to do this:

```
objdef anobj();
if(anobj){
  //initialize check is true
}else{
  //cannot use object right now
}
```

not just for initialization, but a check for its ability to be used.

Comment: Note that `objdef anobj();` is a (local) function declaration; if you want to use a constructow without arguments, use `objdef anobj;`.

Comment: `objdef anobj();` declares a function called `anobj` which takes no parameters and returns an instance of `objdef`.

Comment: If you mean: check if the object is valid. Don't do that.
If you get problem creating an object just throw an exception in the constructor.

Comment: Its for an assignment.  I need to be able to fill in bad values when it is not properly initialized, but I want to be able to check at any time if it is ok to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way `istream` does it is by providing an implicit conversion to `void*`

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/operator_voidpt/
- [stream output and implicit void* cast operator function invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277678/stream-output-and-implicit-void-cast-operator-function-invocation)

**Update** In reaction to the comments, the Safe Bool Idiom would be a far better solution to this: (*code directly [taken from that page](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool2.html)*)

```
  class Testable {
    bool ok_;
    typedef void (Testable::*bool_type)() const;
    void this_type_does_not_support_comparisons() const {}
  public:
    explicit Testable(bool b=true):ok_(b) {}

    operator bool_type() const {
      return ok_==true ? 
        &Testable::this_type_does_not_support_comparisons : 0;
    }
  };

  template <typename T> 
    bool operator!=(const Testable& lhs,const T& rhs) {
    lhs.this_type_does_not_support_comparisons();   
      return false; 
    } 
  template <typename T>
    bool operator==(const Testable& lhs,const T& rhs) {
    lhs.this_type_does_not_support_comparisons();
      return false;     
    }
```

**The article by Bjorn Karlsson contains a [reusable implementation](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool3.html) for the Safe Bool Idiom**

---

#### Old sample:

For enjoyment, I still show the straight forward implementation with operator void* overloading, for clarity and also to show the problem with that:

```
#include <iostream>

struct myclass
{
     bool m_isOk;

     myclass() : m_isOk(true) { }
     operator void* () const { return (void*) (m_isOk? 0x1 : 0x0); }
};

myclass instance;

int main()
{
    if (instance)
        std::cout << "Ok" << std::endl;

    // the trouble with this:
    delete instance; // no compile error !
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is not safe code. I think you would like to see this : [The Safe Bool Idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html)

Comment: One could write `delete instance` and the compiler wouldn't even generate error : http://ideone.com/wv9mA

Comment: @Nawaz: excellent link. Does this mean that iostream library has the same 'flaw' - it does provide the operator void* IIRC

Comment: Yes. It was written and standardized a way before all this research and scrutiny.

Comment: Were it me, I would change `return ok_==true ? x : 0;` with `return ok_ ? x : 0;`. Comparing a `bool` to `true` is a no-op, and I find it that it clutters the code.

Comment: @Rob: `code directly [taken from that page][1]`. Let's not discuss style. I agree with you, but it's not about style here, IMHO

Comment: Note (on the Safe Bool Idiom): within a class the method name *need* be qualified by the class name to take its address... I had unfortunate (and unexpected) compiler errors on this, and gcc is not always helpful (especially in templates...)

Answer (score 3):

This is best accomplished using the [safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).

You provide an implicit conversion to a member-function-pointer, which allows instances of the type to be used in conditions but not implicitly convertyed to `bool`.

Answer (score 2):

You need a (default) constructor and an `operator bool()()`.

```
class X {
     public: 
     operator bool ()const{
          //... return a boolean expression
     }
};
```

usage:

```
X x; // note: no brackets!

if( x ) {
  ....
}
```

Comment: -1; that makes your class implicitly convert to built in integer types. This will compile: `int i = X();`

Comment: @Joe Gauterin: thanks - that's true.  It's good to know the limitations of an otherwise succinct and to-the-point piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create an `operator bool` function (or as boost does, an `unspecified_bool_type` that has certain improved properties I can't recall offhand). You may also want to create `operator!` (For some reason I seem to recall iostreams do this too).